# Minimizing re-drawing for visualization of large graphs

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, cairo

I am working on software for visualizing graph algorithms. The graphs can get pretty large (tens of thousands of nodes). In this case, drawing the current state of the graph is slow. Right now the drawing code is of the form:

```
cairo_push_group(cr);
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
cairo_paint(cr);
... // drawing vertices and edges with styles 
    // corresponding to the current stage of the algorithm
cairo_stroke(cr);
cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_surface_flush(surface);
XFlush(d);
```

The feature I am struggling with is dragging the graph, whereby the user can click any point and drag the whole graph. The re-drawings (i.e. the "..." part in the above code) simply don't keep up.

The question is: is there a way to make the change of transformation matrix (i.e. the application of `cairo_translate`) be reflected on the screen without re-drawing?

I wrote the following small complete program to experiment with this, but am not succeeding in producing a positive result. This is indicated in the comment in `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//This function should give us a new x11 surface to draw on.
cairo_surface_t* create_x11_surface(Display *d, int *x, int *y)
{
    Drawable da;
    int screen;
    cairo_surface_t* sfc;
    Screen *scr;

    screen = DefaultScreen(d);
    scr = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);
    if (!*x || !*y) {
       *x = WidthOfScreen(scr)/2; *y = HeightOfScreen(scr)/2;
       da = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, *x, *y, 0, 0,
                                0);
       //fullscreen (d, da);
    }
    else
        da =
            XCreateSimpleWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, *x, *y, 0, 0, 0);
    XSelectInput(d, da, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | KeyPressMask | ButtonMotionMask | StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d, da);

    sfc = cairo_xlib_surface_create(d, da, DefaultVisual(d, screen), *x, *y);

    return sfc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open display\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int x=500, y=500;
    cairo_surface_t* surface = create_x11_surface(d, &x, &y);
    cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(surface);
    char *text = argv[1];
    size_t text_len = 0;
    XEvent e;

    if (argc != 2)
        text = NULL;
    else
        text_len = strlen(text);

    int last_delta_x = 0, last_delta_y = 0;
    int drag_start_x, drag_start_y;
    bool firstDraw = true;
    while(1)
    {

        if (XPending(cairo_xlib_surface_get_display(surface))) {
            XNextEvent(cairo_xlib_surface_get_display(surface), &e);
            switch(e.type) {
            case ButtonPress:
                drag_start_x = e.xbutton.x; drag_start_y = e.xbutton.y;
                break;
            case ButtonRelease:
                last_delta_x = 0; last_delta_y = 0;
                break;
            case MotionNotify:
                cairo_translate(cr, e.xmotion.x - drag_start_x - last_delta_x,
                                e.xmotion.y - drag_start_y - last_delta_y);
                last_delta_x = e.xmotion.x - drag_start_x;
                last_delta_y = e.xmotion.y - drag_start_y;
                break;
            case ConfigureNotify:
                cairo_xlib_surface_set_size(surface, e.xconfigure.width, e.xconfigure.height);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Dropping unhandled XEevent.type = %d.\n",
                        e.type);
            }

        }

        if (firstDraw) {
            cairo_push_group(cr);
            cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
            cairo_paint(cr);

            cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1, 0);
            cairo_move_to(cr, 0, 0);
            cairo_line_to(cr, 256, 256);
            cairo_move_to(cr, 256, 0);
            cairo_line_to(cr, 0, 256);
            cairo_set_line_width(cr, 10.0);
            cairo_stroke(cr);
            cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
            // firstDraw = false;
            // If the above is uncommented, translation is not reflected
        }
        cairo_paint(cr);
        cairo_surface_flush(surface);
        XFlush(d);

        sleep(0.1);
    }

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: store the nodes in a quad-tree?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah How is this relevant to the question? Note that, sometimes, the graph is scaled down so that all the nodes are in the visible area. The loop that draws tens of thousands filled circles takes time. My question is really whether I can somehow re-draw the whole thing translated all at once instead of re-drawing the individual elements.

Comment: It allows you to compute the visible nodes in O(log N) time; if they are the same nodes then you can use the previous drawing and translate it; otherwise either crop the drawing and add new nodes or delete it and redraw.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah Suppose that all nodes are in the visible area both before and now (only now they need to be shifted a bit). Which `cairo` function allows me to use the previous drawing without having to draw it once again after applying the translation?

Comment: IDK about the specifics of cairo, but every decent self-respecting graphics library should have some sort of static graphics buffer which you can draw to, and later blit to some position on the screen graphics context.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah That's the problem. Cairo has groups and you see the usage in my example. You can push into a group and then pop from it into the context. This helps avoid flickering, but I did not notice any functions to store those drawings for future use...

Comment: How about cairo_pop_group()? That gives you the contents of the group as a pattern. cairo_pop_group_to_source() is just cairo_set_source(cairo_pop_group()) (with correct reference handling)

Comment: @UliSchlachter Thanks! Do you know if I can somehow glue several such patterns into a single one? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/35969970/2725810)