# Cairo: grabbing the whole drawing as a pattern

Tags: c++, graphics, cairo

I am probably missing something conceptual about `cairo`. I draw using the following helper class:

```
struct GroupLock {
    GroupLock(Graphics &g) : g_(g) {
        cairo_push_group(g_.cr);
    }

    ~GroupLock() {
        cairo_pop_group_to_source(g_.cr);
        cairo_paint(g_.cr);
        cairo_surface_flush(g_.surface);
        XFlush(g_.display);
    }
private:
    Graphics &g_;
};
```

All my drawing functions are of the form:

```
void drawSomething(Graphics &g) {
    GroupLock lock{g}; (void)lock;
    ... // some drawing
}
```

Each call to such a drawing function sets the *source* (by virtue of using `GroupLock`) and makes the previous *source* unreachable. How can I modify this code to "concatenate" the *source*s instead? I would like be able to grab the whole drawing as a pattern by doing:

```
cairo_pattern_t *p_ = cairo_get_source(g_.cr);
cairo_pattern_reference(p_);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for hours, here it is! All that needed to be done is to modify the constructor to read like this:

```
p_ = cairo_get_source(g_.cr);
cairo_pattern_reference(p_);

cairo_push_group(g_.cr);
cairo_set_source (g_.cr, p_);
cairo_paint(g_.cr);
cairo_pattern_destroy(p_);
```

Comment: I would try to look at it more but I'm afraid I don't use C++ and this is not the area of Cairo I'm most knowledgeable in. I was just looking through the old [tag:cairo] questions and found this.

Answer (score 0):

For future people wondering, the function that I believe to be the "correct" way to do this is [`cairo_push_group`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-push-group) and [`cairo_pop_group`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-pop-group) which will create a new group and allow one to draw to it, and then subsequently get the drawing result as a pattern, which can then be set as a source. Cairo provides a convenience function for the latter in the form of [`cairo_pop_group_to_source`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-pop-group-to-source), which pops the group and sets it as a source, as well as performing memory management for you.